Self-confinement of $N$-body gravitational systems
Consider $N=2$ point particles (each having unit mass) interacting via Newtonian gravity in the usual 3-dimensional space. There is a simple criterion to assess whether the system is bounded or not: the total "kinetic"+"potential" energy should be negative.
I have a set of related questions and find no clear discussion, so here I am asking for references. The questions do not refer to well-tuned initial conditions but to "almost all initial configurations".

Consider a generic $N$: what do we know about the possible "boundedness" of the system? Is the system's fate to expel particles over time till we are left with a very low $N$?

Imagine building such a system with a certain initial condition. I guess that there is an initial transient where some particles are expelled (their orbits go to infinity and are lost forever). After the "evaporation" of these particles, will the system be "cold enough" to be stably bound over time? (I guess that the particles that escape must have enough kinetic energy to escape the mean gravitational field: they carry away energy from the system, effectively "cooling" it)



Found this while researching my own problem: https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2013/04/aa20665-12/aa20665-12.html

It's a little artificial--there are artificial boundary conditions imposed for the thermodynamic arguments--but it does suggest you can get a pretty good idea of an n-body system's stability, for sufficiently large n such that statistics is meaningful, out of just a few parameters.

Short answer: you’re asking about the general solution to the $n$ body problem, which has been proven not to exist. For $n>2$, we know absolutely nothing about the boundedness of the system without either numerical integration (which is slow and inaccurate) or watching it unfold (which is much slower).
In $n=2$, you’re right that negative total mechanical energy means boundedness, and that in many three-body or $n>3$ configurations, all but two masses end up being ejected. But you’re asking if we know if the system is “bound” or not in the sense that we know that the system will/won’t end up just ejecting $n-2$ masses and becoming an actually-bound state.
If that ejection happens, and the final two masses have negative mechanical energy when the other masses are sufficiently far away as to be neglected, then yes, we know that the system is bound. But you can’t tell that that’s going to happen without numerically integrating the system for an indeterminate period of time. In fact, it might never happen, given that there are stable solutions to the 3 body problem. Given that the problem is unsolvable in the general case, you will never be able to tell if the $n$ masses even do eject any of themselves, let alone the number of masses ejected leaves two to remain in a stable orbit, let alone when that will happen.

Dear @controlgroup, thank you for your answer, it has some interesting insight. I am well aware of the "3-body problem": I am not asking about the general solution, only about boundedness criteria (the information about "boundedness" is much less than the information contained in the exact trajectories). I wonder if, in the specialistic literature, there are exact, or approximate, boundedness criteria. Conversely, I wonder if there is a theorem stating that the only possible criterion is "solve for the exact trajectories".

As far as I’m aware, boundedness is still open in $n$ body systems because it’s impossible to determine final trajectories at any given time (and thus impossible to determine if any masses have yet been ejected) except by numerical integration.
